# Apache common compress giving weird errors on inclusion to android project

Tags: java, android, gradle, apache-commons, apache-commons-compress

I am getting weird errors ever since I have included apache common compress in my gradle file.

Here how I did it

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19'
```

These are the errors I am getting

Java Errors

```
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 67902 > 65536)
```

D8 Errors

```
Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 67902 > 65536)
```

I have searched everywhere, cant seem to understand even what the errors are supposed to mean. Can somebody help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a multidex issue, since the limit of 64k methods is exceeded. Do you have multidex enabled in your project? Have a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex